# How to enable SSL for JMX for Jetty server

Tags: java, ssl, jetty, jmx, jconsole

I am trying to enable secure (SSL) JMX connection for service on Jetty server. All steps are done on one PC for simplifying.

I generate key:

```
keytool -genkey -alias myKeyServer -keyalg RSA -validity 365 -keystore myKeyServerStore.keystore -storepass 12345678 -keypass 12345678 -dname "CN=John Galt, OU=ADS, O=Company, L=Jersey, S=Jersey, C=US"
```

Then export it:

```
keytool -export -alias myKeyServer -keystore myKeyServerStore.keystore -file myKeyServer.cer -storepass 12345678
```

Then importing it:

```
keytool -import -alias myKeyServer -file myKeyServer.cer -keystore myKeyServer.truststore -storepass 12345678 -noprompt
```

Then I start standalone Jetty:

```
 java -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=true
 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1616
 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=true
 -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=\"C:\Java\jdk1.7.0_07\bin\myKeyServerStore.keystore\"
 -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=12345678
 -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=\"C:\Java\jdk1.7.0_07\bin\myKeyServer.truststore\" 
 -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=12345678
 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl.need.client.auth=true
 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.registry.ssl=true
 -jar start.jar
```

It starts successfully. Then I launch JConsole:

```
jconsole 
 -J-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=\"C:\Java\jdk1.7.0_07\bin\myKeyServer.truststore\"
 -J-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=12345678
 -J-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=\"C:\Java\jdk1.7.0_07\bin\myKeyServerStore.keystore\"
 -J-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=12345678
 192.168.0.1:1616
```

And after it I get an Exception in Jetty server console:

```
java.net.SocketException: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException:
Error constructing implementation (algorithm: Default, provider: SunJSSE,
class: sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLContext)

at javax.net.ssl.DefaultSSLSocketFactory.throwException(Unknown Source)
at javax.net.ssl.DefaultSSLSocketFactory.createSocket(Unknown Source)
at javax.rmi.ssl.SslRMIServerSocketFactory$1.accept(Unknown Source)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$AcceptLoop.executeAcceptLoop(Unknown Source)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$AcceptLoop.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Caused by: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException:
Error constructing implementation (algorithm: Default, provider: SunJSSE,
class: sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLContext)

at java.security.Provider$Service.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(Unknown Source)
at javax.net.ssl.SSLContext.getInstance(Unknown Source)
at javax.net.ssl.SSLContext.getDefault(Unknown Source)
at javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.getDefault(Unknown Source)
at javax.rmi.ssl.SslRMIServerSocketFactory.getDefaultSSLSocketFactory(Unknown Source)
at javax.rmi.ssl.SslRMIServerSocketFactory.<init>(Unknown Source)
at javax.rmi.ssl.SslRMIServerSocketFactory.<init>(Unknown Source)
at sun.management.jmxremote.ConnectorBootstrap.createSslRMIServerSocketFactory(Unknown Source)
at sun.management.jmxremote.ConnectorBootstrap.exportMBeanServer(Unknown Source)
at sun.management.jmxremote.ConnectorBootstrap.startRemoteConnectorServer(Unknown Source)
at sun.management.Agent.startAgent(Unknown Source)
at sun.management.Agent.startAgent(Unknown Source)

Caused by: java.security.PrivilegedActionException:
java.io.FileNotFoundException: "C:\Java\jdk1.7.0_07\bin\myKeyServerStore.keystore"
(╤шэЄръёшўхёър  ю°шсър т шьхэш Їрщыр, шьхэш яряъш шыш ьхЄъх Єюьр)

at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLContext.getDefaultKeyManager(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLContext.<init>(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
... 14 more

Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: "C:\Java\jdk1.7.0_07\bin\myKeyServerStore.keystore"
 (╤шэЄръёшўхёър  ю°шсър т шьхэш Їрщыр, шьхэш яряъш шыш ьхЄъх Єюьр)

at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLContext$2.run(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLContext$2.run(Unknown Source)
... 23 more
```

But if I disable SSL, JConsole can successfully connect to Jetty. Does anybody know how to solve it?

Comment: The problem was in not needed '\"' symbols in path. Dumb mistake